# Leaflet enable all overlays by default

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the [leaflet.timedimension](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension) plugin to animate GPX trails and I would like to show multiple GPX paths at once with the possibility to deselect one or the other.

This works, but as only the first overlay in the leaflet control is enabled by default the user has to explicitly include the other GPX trails which I would like to avoid.

I've now tried to hack a bit around via:

```
$(".leaflet-control-layers-overlays label input").prop('checked', true)
```

and this works partially: all options are selected but still only the first GPX trail is shown. When doing

```
$(".leaflet-control-layers-overlays label input").trigger('click');
```

then only one trail is clicked depending on where I put it ('on('ready', function () {...}')

What is the proper way in leaflet to trigger an overlay click?

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to add both layers to the map:

```
geoJson1.addTo(map);
geoJson2.addTo(map);
```